# Timer in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Can anyone please tell my why this doesn't work?

```
(function() {
    window.Test = {};
})();

Test.Timers = {
    c: null,
    startTimer: function() { c = 0; setTimeout(this.doWork, 0); },
    doWork: function() {
        c++;
        alert(c);
        setTimeout(this.doWork, 0);
    }
};
```

When I call Test.Timers.startTimer(), it only alerts once with a 1.
Thanks

Comment: Because `doWork` has been detached from `this` when you pass it to `setTimeout`. So the second `this.doWork` is giving you a different `this` value.

Comment: What would be the correct way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Just change that one line to: `startTimer: function() { c = 0; setTimeout(this.doWork.bind(this), 0); },`

Comment: I went ahead and replaced 'this' with 'Test.Timers' and it works. Does this seem like a bad solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method doesn't "remember" its owner (its `this`); you can copy a method from one object to another, and treat it like any other function. It only has the right owner when you actually call it using dot-notation, e.g. `this.doWork()`.

So your problem is that you're passing the function `this.doWork` to `setTimeout`, and then it gets called as a function without knowing its owner, and suddenly its `this` is `window` instead of your timer object. To fix this, you need to keep track of your `this` yourself. For example, you might write:

```
Test.Timers = (function () {
    var newTimer = {
        c: null,
        startTimer: function() {
            this.c = 0;
            setTimeout(function () { newTimer.doWork(); }, 0);
        },
        doWork: function() {
            this.c++;
            alert(this.c);
            setTimeout(function () { newTimer.doWork(); }, 0);
        }
    };
    return newTimer;
 })();
```

or:

```
Test.Timers = (function () {
    var startTimer = function() {
        newTimer.c = 0;
        setTimeout(doWork, 0);
    };
    var doWork = function() {
        newTimer.c++;
        alert(newTimer.c);
        setTimeout(doWork, 0);
    };
    var newTimer = {
        c: null,
        startTimer: startTimer,
        doWork: doWork
    };
    return newTimer;
 })();
```

(Note that I also changed `c` to `this.c` or `newTimer.c` where necessary, since your version refers repeatedly to `window.c`. Also note that in the second version, if you don't need external code to be able to access `c`, you can change it to a local variable, making things cleaner.)

Comment: It is so confusing like this though. In my code, I went ahead and replaced 'this' with 'Test.Timers' and now it works. Do you think my solution is a bad idea? Thanks.

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle: Without more context, it's hard to be sure, but -- in general, that's not the best approach. (And I hope that, in addition to changing `this` to `Test.Timers` where needed, you also changed `c` to `Test.Timers.c` where needed? Because otherwise your code is broken, even if it "works".)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment to ruakh's answer, I prefer the following approach, myself:

```
Test.Timers = (function () {
    var this_ = {
        c: null,
        startTimer: function() { this_.c = 0; setTimeout(this_.doWork, 0); },
        doWork: function() {
            this_.c++;
            alert(this_.c);
            setTimeout(this_.doWork, 0);
        }
    };
    return this_;
})();
```

That way, the meaning is clear as `this_` looks like `this`, and all you have to do is get used to the closure pattern of making an anonymous function and calling it right away. Also note that I fixed your reference to `c` to refer to `this_.c` instead of a global variable `c`.

Alternatively, you can use `.bind()` to bind the function's `this` to a particular thing. This is built-in to Chrome's V8, at least, and perhaps Firefox as well:

```
Test.Timers = {
    c: null,
    startTimer: function() { this.c = 0; setTimeout(this.doWork, 0); },
    doWork: function() {
        this.c++;
        alert(this.c);
        setTimeout(this.doWork, 0);
    }
};
Test.Timers.startTimer = Test.Timers.startTimer.bind(Test.Timers);
Test.Timers.doWork = Test.Timers.doWork.bind(Test.Timers);
```